# Обновлять информацию об онлайне пользователей без перезагрузки страницы раз в минуту

Tags: php

У меня есть сайт на php, и на нем есть личные страницы пользователей. Подскажите, как лучше обновлять информацию из базы данных об их онлайне без перезагрузки страницы раз в минуту?

Comment: Лучше всего с использованием websocket. но для простых сайтов из за одной цифры с ним заморачиваться не надо. Остается раз в минуту запрашивать у сервера текущее количество с помощью AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Для получения количества пользователей онлайн можно сделать endpoint (маршрут в роутере при его использовании) или файл `.php`, который будет возвращать данную информацию.

Инициировать запрос на обновление можно с помощью JS по таймеру. Посредством AJAX запрашиваем данную информацию. По идентификатору блока находим данный div-блок и заменяем число.